# How can I identify points that share similar attribute with polygon features based on the attribute & distance between the two?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer, spatial-join, proximity, select-by-location

For Example; if both the point & polygon features have an ID field, I need to flag the points if they share the same ID as a neighboring polygon & are w/in 2000ft of each other.  I have tried a spatial join, but I am having problems choosing the correct parameters to identify the points correctly. I have already created buffers around the points for the distance, but I am unsure how to select by location based only on matching attributes. It's selecting ALL the buffers.

Comment: Any selects after the first should be set to "select from existing selection." Or save out your selections to a temporary file and work with that, which has the same effect.